# Why can't I initialize NSTimer in my class property?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, properties, nstimer

I have my code as follow. It shows error "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11". If I initialize my timer in the comment part instead, then it will be alright.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var networkManager = NetworkManager.sharedInstance

//    var timer: Timer?
    var timer: Timer? = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func doSomething() {
    }

}
```

It's interesting that I can not initialize the timer in the property, but I can initialize a singleton instead.

What's the reason that makes the difference?
Maybe about runloop or something? Can anyone explain that? Thanks.

Comment: Because the initialization if probably occurring before any run loops are setup for the timer to be able to use.

Comment: That, and the fact that you can't access `self` to refer to the instance until after initialization.

Comment: @vacawama has the whole answer.

Comment: @allenlinli did you test my answer below?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I think it's not the reason. Default run loops are setup with UIApplication, so it should be earlier than the runloop of the Timer.